# search for attribute in parent node and get value of Child node attribute

Tags: java, xml, node.js, xpath

### **Short version:**

Search for attribute in parent-node and get attribute-values of child-nodes.

---

### **Long version:**

I have the following part of a xml-File:

```
<include template="directory/file.xml">
        <param name="permission" value="permission_value"/>
        <param name="path" value="path_value"/>
</include>
```

I check the whole file with the xPath-request `"//include[@template]"` and recive a nodelist . Now I want to look for the `<param name="XXX" value="XXX_value"/>` nodes, which are the childs of my xPath-result-nodes.

```
[initialize xPath before...]

String expression ="//include[@template]";                                                                          
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

if(nodeList.getLength()>0)
{
   for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++)
   {
      NodeList childList = nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes();

      for(int k=0; k<childList.getLength(); k++)
      {         
        // System.out.println(childList.item(k).getNodeName()); --> prints "#text" 

        String name = childList.item(k).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").toString().replace("\"", "").replace("name=", "");
        String value = childList.item(k).getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").toString().replace("\"", "").replace("value=", "");

        System.out.println("Key: "+key+" Value: "+value);
      }
   }
}
```

But this code doesn´t work for me beacause currently there is no output at all apart of the comment with the "#text" output. Not even "Key: Value: " is printed.

How to get the values of the `param`-childs if I search for `include`-nodes ?

**Edit 1:**

```
System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
```

delivers 1(correct)

but:

```
System.out.println(childList.getLength());
```

delivers 3 which is very weird

**Edit 2:**

It seems like if he can´t get the attributes. I tried to get the attributes with

`String key = childList.item(k).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").toString();` and recived a `NullPointerException` at this line.

Comment: Can you show us what the output is? If any. I don't see where the 'i' comes from. I think it should be 0? And I think that getNamedItem returns the value of the attribute, so you don't have to replace all those characters.

Comment: There is no output at all.

Comment: Can you give us some more information? I would like to know the value of 'nodeList.getLength' and why are you using 'i'?

Comment: @cvesters fixed that. The i was from another for-loop

Comment: Why not grab the "parameters" direcly?  "//include[@template]/param", then walk through it?

Comment: @MarvinSmit because there could be several of this include nodes in a file and I have to strictly seperate them. It is neccessary to check each <include> seperately due to this fact.

Comment: The null pointer exception is due to the fact that there is a hidden child containing the new line, and tabs. So you need to check if the child is an element node.

Comment: @cvesters How can i do that

Comment: `ChildList.item(k).getNodeType.equals(Node. ELEMENT_NODE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String expression ="//include[@template]";                                                                          
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for(int i=0; i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
    NodeList childList = nodeList.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for(int k=0; k<childList.getLength(); k++){         
        Node child = childList.item(k);
        if(child instanceof Element){
            Element elem = (Element)child;
            if("param".equals(elem.getLocalName())){
                String name = elem.getAttribute("name");
                String value = elem.getAttribute("value");
                System.out.println("Name: "+name+" Value: "+value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```